# Import org.acra.* into android project gives error.

Tags: java, android, acra

I want to add ACRA into android project. I do the steps according to the link:
http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/BasicSetup

I added jar file to the lib folder in the project and I added it to build. But when I try to add some ACRA's rows in the java code like

```
import org.acra.*
```

or

```
ACRA.init(this);
```

I receive the errors in Eclipse.
So, how can I remove this errors? Thanks.

Comment: What errors are you receiving?

Comment: Hi Marvin, it looks like eclipse can't import acra libraries. For ACRA.init(this) command I receive suggestion from Eclipse to create ACRA Constant. For import org.acra.* I receive error that looks like this library has wrong name and doesn't exists.

Comment: Hi Marvin, you are right. When I read your answer, I added jar file again. I did it wrong before. I also did Clean Project as you said. Now I don't have errors in import org.acra.* rows. I still have errors in @ReportCrash row and in ACRA.init() row. I'll try to do with it something. Thank you very much! Tatiana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-add the jar file again and a Project->Clean should take care of it.