# Application crashing after launch (on smartphone and emulator)

Tags: android, crash, acra

My app crashing immediately after launch and I don't know why (I'm beginner). I suppose that problem is Android SDK libraries. Earlier (before I downlaoaded new Androidk SDK's with SDK Manager, everything works fine, and Elcipse exports good *.apk without any erorrs). I  also tried install new eclipse with new Android SDK and ADT plugin on my second laptop and the problem is the same. 
Here it is screenshot from emulator: http://speedy.sh/DypGB/error.jpg

And here is log from logcat: http://speedy.sh/h6DFm/log.txt

Someone can help me?

Comment: Maybe [this][1] helps? 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702396/import-org-acra-into-android-project-gives-error

Comment: Can you please post the pic and log here instead of creating a link to some other website

Answer (score 0):

is the acra jar file in your java build path?

1. copy the acra jar into your project folder
2. right click the project, select build path -> configure build path
3. click the libraries tab
4. click "add external jar" and pick the copied jar

Comment: I already have acra-4.2.3 in my project ( sexisfun>lib>acra-4.2.3 ) It look like Eclipse doesn't see this library.